# Continuation of the function after calling setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As planned, the getUsers () function should be called after the progress_bar bar has been processed, and the modal window will be closed. But in practice, it is called while the progress bar is still running in the loop.
How to fix it.

```
$("#progess-modal").modal('show');
            vm.progress=0;    
   this.progress_bar();
           axios.post('http://task.ru.xsph.ru/task.php',
                        'text='+this.text
                    )
                        .then(res => {
                            this.getUsers()
                            this.closeNav()
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            showModal:true
                            this.getUsers()
                        })
```

And progress bar function:

```
 progress_bar:function()
            {
                var vm=this
                var width=5
                $("#progess-modal").modal('show');
                vm.progress=0;
                setInterval(function(){
                    vm.progress+=width;
                    if(vm.progress>=100){
                        $("#progess-modal").modal('hide');
                        return}
                },500)
            }
```

As planned, the getUsers () function should be called after the progress_bar bar has been processed, and the modal window will be closed. But in practice, it is called while the progress bar is still running in the loop.
How to fix it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Open-> Add-on Task

Comment: Are you wanting execution to stop at `this.progressBar()` until the progress gets to 100%? That's not how `setInterval()` works.

Comment: Also, what's the point of the progress bar if it's not actually reflecting progress, but instead just implementing what appears to be an artificial delay?

Comment: Yes, now I need an artificial delay.

Comment: add `var busy = true;` up top. add `if(!busy) return` in progress_bar, and add `busy = false;` in the then(), then you can close the modal in the then() as well...

Answer (score 0):

In JS, all the statements are synchronous. By default, it doesn't wait for functions like progress_bar(). Moreover, setInterval is also synchronous. It means that your progress_bar() function doesn't wait for set Interval to complete to return. In order to do that, you need to make progress_bar() function return a promise.

```
progress_bar: function() {
    var vm = this   
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var width = 5
        $("#progess-modal").modal('show');
        vm.progress = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            vm.progress += width;
            if (vm.progress >= 100) {
                $("#progess-modal").modal('hide');
                resolve();
            }
        }, 500)
    })
}
```

Then in the main code,

```
$("#progess-modal").modal('show');
vm.progress = 0;
var that = this;
this.progress_bar().then(function(res) {
    axios.post('http://task.ru.xsph.ru/task.php',
            'text=' + that.text
        )
        .then(res => {
            that.getUsers()
            that.closeNav()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            showModal: true
            that.getUsers()
        })
})
```

This makes sure that progress_bar() function only returns when you actually want to return i.e. inside setInterval(). the `.then()` is then run after you resolve the Promise

Comment: Your example is good, but the first two sentences are completely false. The majority of JS statements are synchronous. You have to mark functions `async` or return a `Promise` to make them asynchronous.